# MySQL procedure error - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have an error when I want to run in MySQL phpmyadmin this procedure.

```
  DELIMITER //
create or replace procedure proc_ex_3a(in v_adr varchar)
BEGIN
    select * from Furnizori WHERE v_adr LIKE '%8' order by v_adr;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The syntax should be fine, but this error occurs

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near ') BEGIN
> select numef from Furnizori WHERE v_adr LIKE '%8' order by v_adr; ...' at line 1

Comment: Why should it be fine? On what basis are you making that assertion? What do you know that we don't???

Comment: VARCHAR is not valid here. It should be CHAR - e.g. CHAR(20) (or just CHAR also seems to be acceptable!)

Comment: 'The CHAR and VARCHAR types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html